# Removing a view or range of views from a LinearLayout causes a NullPointerException in a call to unFocus

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I have a HorizontalScrollView containing a LinearLayout which is used to display a file tree ribbon

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content_ribbon_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_file_ribbon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Items are added to the LinearLayout as the user navigates to them

```
void addRibbonItem(final Node node) {
        final TextView view = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shard_ribbon_item, mRibbon, false);
        view.setText(node.getName());

        mRibbon.addView(view);
        mRibbon.postDelayed(() -> mRibonScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT), 17);
```

When an item is clicked, all of the items to the right of it should be removed.

I have tried to do this with the removeViewsInLayout method, as well as repeatedly removing the final view.

(Ignore the lack of bounds checks)

```
    view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        mRibbon.removeViewsInLayout(mRibbon.indexOfChild(view) + 1, mRibbon.getChildCount());
    });


    view.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
        final int index = mRibbon.indexOfChild(view);
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) mRibbon.removeViewAt(mRibbon.getChildCount());
    });
```

Both of these methods give the same exception

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewsInternal(ViewGroup.java:4691)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewsInLayout(ViewGroup.java:4539)
                                                                      at com.tpb.projects.repo.content.ContentActivity.lambda$-com_tpb_projects_repo_content_ContentActivity_lambda$1(ContentActivity.java:67)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Removing and re-adding the Views does work, but I don't believe that this is a good solution.

```
    view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        final ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i <= mRibbon.indexOfChild(view); i++) {
            views.add(mRibbon.getChildAt(i));
        }
        mRibbon.removeAllViews();
        for(View item : views) {
            mRibbon.addView(item);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. Use the child element to get a reference to the parent.
2. Cast the parent to a ViewGroup so that you get access to the removeView method and use that.

```
((ViewGroup)scrollChildLayout.getParent()).removeView(scrollChildLayout);
```

and not like this:

```
//scrollView.removeView(scrollChildLayout);
```

Comment: This lets me remove the View that is clicked, but I get the same crash when trying to remove a range of views from the ViewGroup, which is what I need to do.

Comment: What about call requestChildFocus

Before remove?

Comment: That will also crash, because the ViewGroup returns null for getFocusedChild(), which is required for requestChildFocus